# Writing an if then statement for if a parameter is selected (not Null) in Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, modelbuilder

I have a tool I'm trying to create in model builder. I have run into a problem as I have basically no experience with python. I'm trying to basically use the calculate value tool and an if then statement to determine if a model parameter (type String) has a value inputted to it by the user, if it does then go one direction in model builder and if not go another. Something to the effect of the picture below:
[image]

The Second picture is of the model with the properties of the string and the tool (in the lower right)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  I checked the help for the calculate Value tool. It says: "Variables created in ModelBuilder can be used by this tool, but variables desired for use in the expression parameter cannot be connected to the Calculate Value tool. To use them in the expression, enclose the variable name in percent signs (%). For example, if you want to divide a variable named 'Input' by 100, your expression would be %Input%/100."  So, ModelBuilder parameter names have to be surrounded by percent signs to be passed into the Calculate Value tool (It has to be %String%, not String).  I have changed the code to show the correct syntax.

The String parameter is never Null, it is initialized as '', so the condition has been change to only return False when values of String are greater than ''.   It returns true if String == ''.

You have several problems.  In Python you must set up a def function to use a code_block.  I have flipped your test logic so that it now tests for actual string values and not Null values.  ModelBuilder may return '' for what you consider to be a Null String parameter value.  So you may need to change the test to be just values greater than '', not values greater than or equal to ''.  None should used to test for real Null values if you are dealing with field values from a table or a parameter from a script tool interface.  You are also missing a colon at the end of your if statement as kttii mentioned.  Also, this is setting a Boolean parameter based on the Data Type value you have chosen, not a text string, so your return values are wrong and you need to change them to return real Boolean values.

So the expression must change to:

```
nullTest(%String%)
```

So the code_block code must change to:

```
def nullTest(String):
    print("The value of String is {0}".format(String))
    if String > '':
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: That worked beautifully with one small issue. None does not seem to equal no value. With no input, it returns it as false still. It states: Executing (Calculate Value (2)): CalculateValue nullTest(String) "def nullTest(String):\n    if String == None:\n        return True\n    else:\n        return False" Boolean
Start Time: Thu Jun 23 12:21:37 2016
Value = 0

Comment: Well then it is a blank string, since "Null" is not Null it is the word Null as a string.  So I have changed it to if String == '':

Comment: I actually have flipped the logic to test for values that are not Null (i.e., they are a blank string or a real string value).  If you get a return value of 1 when you consider the String parameter to be Null, it is actually a blank string.

Comment: I meant to say "If you get a return value of 0 with the new code when you consider the String parameter to be Null, it is actually a blank string."

Comment: Thanks for all the great help again! unfortunately the same error occurs with: if String == '' as well as 0 or various versions of NULL that I've tried

Comment: Don't try to test for Null.  Flip the test so that it checks for nonNull values and returns False, otherwise it returns True (for whatever the hell ModelBuilder is giving you).  See my latest code.

Comment: yeah I had just tested 'five' and it returned true somehow when the input was five as well

Comment: I have added a print statement to the code to see if it tells you the real value of String.  It might have to be changed to a AddMessage method if the print method doesn't work when you run the Model.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't understood what you were saying, but I do now. I tried your latest code and it still didn't work. Your idea makes sense and it doesn't make sense why it wouldn't work:

Comment: Then I do not think String is the actual name of the parameter, only the parameter's type.  I would have to see the parameter set up to be sure.  How do you get this parameter and pass it to the Calculate Value tool?  You need to post a screen shot of this part of the model  also.

Comment: With the print statement added, I get the same result whether there is a value or not. It still returns it as true. CalculateValue nullTest(String) "def nullTest(String):\n    print("The value of String is {0}".format(String))\n    if String >= '':\n        return False\n    else:\n        return True" Boolean
Start Time: Thu Jun 23 13:34:38 2016
Value = 1

Comment: Post Screenshots.  Start by editing your post and adding a screenshot of this portion of the model to show this tool and its inputs

Comment: Yeah sorry I was getting there. I keep responding to your comments after you've made a new comment. I edited the original post with a screenshot of the model and the properties of the string

Comment: String does not pass a parameter to the Calculate Value tool.  %String% does.  See the help:  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm

Comment: I get this error after adding the percents, which I should have realized to use. I wondered if it was because of the definition line, but def nullTest(five) didn't work and had the same error: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: nullTest(five) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'five' is not defined

Comment: I additionally tried def nullTest(%String%) and that came up with true instead of false for a null value. Thanks for all the help! I'm going to try to figure out more later.

Comment: So that means that a so called Null value is actually a blank value, ie %String% == ''.  I changed the code to only treat String values greater than '' as not Null and return False.  If %String% == '' the code will return True.   This should be the last fix.  Please check my post as the answer to your question and up vote it.

Comment: This is my first time using this site, so I don't have the reputation to upvote sorry. I feel like we're close, but that didn't work either. There seems to be a problem with no argument given.

Comment: The output is: Executing (Calculate Value): CalculateValue nullTest() "def nullTest(String):\n    print("The value of String is {0}".format(String))\n    if String > '':\n        return False\n    else:\n        return True" Boolean
Start Time: Thu Jun 23 15:27:40 2016
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: nullTest() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: nullTest() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Failed to execute (Calculate Value).

Comment: Additionally if a non-null value is put in the error is: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: nullTest(five) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'five' is not defined

Comment: Interesting enough it works with numbers though if you add apostrophes around String in the if statement: if 'String' > '':

Comment: Adding apostrophes simply means you have made a string with the word String in it and 'String' > '' will always be True.  So 'String' > '' is completely ignoring the String parameter, so the parameter value no longer plays any part in the output if you make that change.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a colon at the end of the if statement.

See this page for more info:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm

Comment: Thanks that helped part of the problem! However when I run the model builder it has an error stating: ERROR 000539: Runtime error SyntaxError: 'return' outside function (<string>, line 2)
Failed to execute (Calculate Value).

Comment: I don't have arcgis but I think that link will help you.  The error you are getting is because you did not enclose the if statement in a defined function.  There are several examples in that link of how to formulate the code as a function in the Code block section.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a code block, you can go for

'False' if !String! is None else 'true'

Comment: I don't think you can do that with Calculate Value.

Comment: In any event, a so called Null value in ModelBuilder does not match a Python value of None.  So even if the syntax works, the test doesn't work.  I think ModelBuilder is actually returning ''.  In any case I think it may be better to flip the logic so that the test is for any real text values (return False), else (return True).  Also, this is not a field calculation and String is a parameter, not a field.

Comment: @Richard Fairhurst I read your comments and I learn. I'll leave my answer up as food for thought and so your comment may profit others. I had not tested my answer in ModelBuilder.